# Regular Expression in Linux command sed giving unterminated 's' command error

Tags: sed, regular-expression

When i run the following sed expression from with a bash script

```
t=$(sed -n "s/^([0-9]+\.){2,2}(\*|[0-9]+)(\-.*){0,1}$/p" ./apps/core-website/settings/website.config)
```

it gives the following error:

```
sed: -e expression #1, char 41: unterminated `s' command
```

Comment: The `s` sed command is to `s`ubstitute, but you're not specifying what it is you want to substitute matches with. Also you're using extended regex, while `sed` takes basic regexps by  default. Also `\-` doesn't make sense and `{2,2}` (`\{2,2\}` in BRE) is the same as `{2}`, and ERE `{0,1}` is ERE  `?`

Comment: If it's to print the lines that match the regex, you can just use `grep`, with `-E` for extended regexps (most `sed`s also support `-E` for extended regexps now)

Comment: So `grep -xE '([0123456789]+\.){2}(\*|[0123456789]+)(-.*)?'` (here using `[0123456789]` as `[0-9]` is not guaranteed to match only  0123456789 with either `sed` or `grep` depending on the locale and system).

Comment: Related: [Need to find and replace the semantic version expression from within a config file using sed](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/732798)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is correct, you have not terminated your `s//` command. The pattern should be `s/pattern/replacement/` optionally followed by qualifiers such as `g`, `i`, `p`, etc. You've got `s/pattern/p` so there is no replacement.

You should also be aware that you're using an Extended Regular Expression (ERE) pattern but you haven't told `sed` that you're doing this so it assumes an ordinary Regular Expression. Use `sed -E` for this.

Comment: Speculation: They may want to print the lines matching the regular expression. If so, they should drop the `s` at the start of the expression (and, arguably, switch to `grep -E`).

Comment: @Kusalananda yes, I saw Stéphane's [suggestion](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/732787/regular-expression-in-linux-command-sed-giving-unterminated-s-command-error/732790?noredirect=1#comment1390712_732787) for that solution too, but I decided for a proper answer there was little point speculating until we understood what was required. I'd like to see a sample from the OP's `website.config` too