# Need to find and replace the semantic version expression from within a config file using sed

Tags: text-processing, sed, regular-expression

Following are the contents of the config file

```
{
  "Line1": true,
  "Line2": "\/\/{hostname}\/",
  "version": "2.8.9",
  "Line4": true,
  "Line5": true
}
```

I am using Linux, and I need to find semantic version number 2.8.9 above and store in one variable and replace it with either major, minor or patch version based on the logic in the next variable.

Can someone please suggest the appropriate **sed regex expression** for both finding and replacing the semantic version

These are 2 valid regex expressions for semantic versions

1. `^([0-9]+\.){2,2}(\*|[0-9]+)(\-.*){0,1}$`
2. `^(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)\.(0|[1-9]\d*)(?:-((?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*)(?:\.(?:0|[1-9]\d*|\d*[a-zA-Z-][0-9a-zA-Z-]*))*))?(?:\+([0-9a-zA-Z-]+(?:\.[0-9a-zA-Z-]+)*))?$`

Comment: Seems like JSON ,isn't it?

Comment: Advice to newcomers: If an answer solves your problem, please accept it by clicking the large check mark (✓) next to it and optionally also up-vote it (up-voting requires at least 15 reputation points). If you found other answers helpful, please up-vote them. Accepting and up-voting helps future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are only after the version number then grep could do a better job than sed:

```
$ grep -o '[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]+' infile 
2.8.9
```

But if you are looking to find and replace the version number then try this:

```
$ sed 's/[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+\.[0-9]\+/REPLACEMENT/' infile 

{
  "Line1": true,
  "Line2": "\/\/{hostname}\/",
  "version": "REPLACEMENT",
  "Line4": true,
  "Line5": true
}
```

Comment: thanks dhm for the solution. This works till single digit numbers like 2.8.9, but fall short when any of the numbers goes to double digit. Can you please modify this command in order to handle something like 2.10.11

Comment: Modified as requested.

Answer (score 1):

### Ways to parse JSON

##### Disclaimer, was reading to fast, this is not a search&replace response.

@Kusulandra gave the good one:

```
jq --arg new '3.0.0' '.version = $new' file | sponge file
```

##### With [jq](/questions/tagged/jq):

```
jq -r '.version' file.json
```

##### With [gron](https://github.com/tomnomnom/gron) and GNU [grep](/questions/tagged/grep)

```
gron file.json | grep -oP 'version.*?"\K[^"]+'
```

##### With [go](/questions/tagged/go)

```
package main
import (
   "encoding/json"
   "fmt"
   "io/ioutil"
   "log"
   "os"
)

func main() {
   fileContent, err := os.Open("/tmp/file.json")

   if err != nil {
      log.Fatal(err)
      return
   }

   defer fileContent.Close()

   byteResult, _ := ioutil.ReadAll(fileContent)

   var res map[string]interface{}
   json.Unmarshal([]byte(byteResult), &res)

   fmt.Println(res["version"])
}
```

##### With [json_xs](https://metacpan.org/dist/JSON-XS/view/bin/json_xs) command line

```
json_xs < file.json -t none -e 'print %{ $_ }{version}'
```

Installed via Perl module `JSON::XS`

##### With [perl](/questions/tagged/perl)

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict; use warnings;

use File::Slurp;
use JSON::XS;

my $text = read_file("file.json");
$text = decode_json $text;
print $text->{version};
```

##### with [python](/questions/tagged/python)

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('file.json')

# returns JSON object as a dictionary
# by parsing the data and assigns it to a variable
data = json.load(f)

# print the json value 'version'
print(data['version'])

# Closing file
f.close()
```

##### Output

```
2.8.9
```

Comment: Replacing with `jq+sponge`: `jq --arg new '3.0.0' '.version = $new' file | sponge file`

Comment: Thanks Gilles for your solution, however i need to read the json version from the bash file and replace it using regex and sed (unless some command can achieve it)

Comment: @VikasArora This is what Gilles is showing. Parsing a JSON file is best done with a JSON-aware tool, such as the most excellent `jq` utility, or with some library, like what Gilles is showing.